# When does proving Tychonoff's theorem not require extensions of the ZF set theory?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, axiom-of-choice

Proving Tychonoff's theorem requires the axiom of choice, in general. For Hausdorff spaces, just the Boolean prime theorem is enough. Is it possible to identify interesting classes of spaces or of index sets for which just the ZF framework is enough?

In particular, what happens (if anything noteworthy) for countably many Riemannian manifolds?

Of course, I am not interested in trivial answers (such as a finite number of non-empty spaces).

Comment: For locales, the theorem holds constructively.

Comment: Just a passing (irrelevant?) remark - which you probably know anyway, but just in case: Tychonoff implies the axiom of choice - i.e., Tychonoff is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @ziggurism I've been reading this claim quite a few times in the last couple of days, and it seems really interesting: can you point to any reference ?

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tychonoff+theorem+for+locales

Answer (score 5):

As an overview of how complicated the relation Tychonoff / AC is, see [these](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/affd/e6e2c4f95eb3aa8ee4e053c5bc8e65550a3f.pdf) [papers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.5844&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which show that for other alternative definitions of compactness (which might be non-equivalent in the absence of AC) we see that the corresponding version of Tychonoff might or might not be equivalent to AC (or weaker versions). (See [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38384987_Definitions_of_compactness_and_the_axiom_of_choice) for a comparison of the definitions themselves).

You don't need Tychonoff for a large class of spaces to prove the axiom of choice: [the proof here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/01.aim/1.htm) shows that if we assume

> The Tychonoff theorem holds for the class of all topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{T})$ such that $|\mathcal{T}| =4$ (which are obviously all compact)

Then full AC must already be true.

In ZF we can certainly show it for the class of all spaces with $|\mathcal{T}|= 2$  because then $X$ is indiscrete and any product of indiscrete spaces is indiscrete hence compact.

Maybe AC is already implied by Tychonoff for topologies of size 3? I think so, because it suffices (in the linked proof) to define the topology as $\{X_i, \{p_i\}, \emptyset\}$, I think, as @bof also noticed.

As to your countable case, this is much weaker. It might even be in ZF if your subclass of spaces (like Riemannian manifolds) is small enough. I'll let others be the judge of that. E.g. it might make a difference of the spaces are second countable and whether you want sequential compactness or other forms)

In summary: it's subtle.

Comment: For a countable product of finite spaces you need something like countable choice so I wouldn't be so sure

Comment: @bof I looked at that already and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: @Max it’s provable in ZF that a countable product $\prod_n k_n$ with all $k_n $ integers, is compact.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : that seems wrong. That means you can prove the compactbess theorem for predicate logic for countably many variables in ZF ? Can you link to a reference ? Or provide a proof ?

Comment: I meant propositional logic

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ah sorry you wrote "integers", I thought you meant finite sets ! Then it doesn't bother me so much, though I'm not sure either (but it would surprise me less)

Comment: @Max integers is essential, because they’re already well-ordered.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes obviously that's the difference. I'll think about it and try to prove it myself for those (for finite sets I was completely lost haha)